# How do I print a web page as a PDF from Firefox (using Adobe) without the URL in the footer?

Tags: firefox, pdf, printing, adobe-acrobat

I have Adobe Acrobat installed on my Windows 7 machine, and I'm trying to print a webpage as a PDF from Firefox. When I do, the URL of the page is automatically placed in the footer. I did uncheck the "Add document information" checkbox in the Adobe PDF Printer Preferences dialog (see image), but this has no effect.

[image: Adobe PDF printer preferences - "add document information" checkbox unchecked]

Is it possible to disable this? Ideally, I'd like to disable it system-wide for all browsers, but failing that, I'll take a Firefox-specific solution.

In Chrome, expanding "More Settings" in the Print dialog and unchecking "Headers and footers" disables this. Is there something similar for Firefox?

[image: Chrome print settings - uncheck "Headers and Footers"]

Comment: Note that the "Add Document Information" option means that relevant metadata is added to the document. And that information is by default not printed, but stored in a specific place in the PDF document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need to do this in Firefox: File > Page Setup > Margins & Header/Footer > Set all of the headers/footers to blank.

You would have the same issue with a regular printer, and since the Adobe PDF function is emulating a printer, it should be done this way...

Comment: Well I'm an idiot. I was mucking around in `about:config` and wondering why setting the value of the `print.print_headerright` (among others) wasn't having any effect. It was probably because the setting was still set in Page Setup... Thanks!

Comment: @MichaelA: For what it's worth, those options in about:config should reflect what's in page setup. I blanked out what I had in print.print_headerright and then it was unset in page setup.